# dpkt ipv6 extension header

Tags: python, parsing, wireshark, pcap, dpkt

I am trying to get ipv6 extension header from pcap packet using dpkt and print it out. But for some reason it didnt work. I have tried many different ways. here is the part of the code that cause the problem. is there anyone have an idea how to solve this?
p.s there is lack of example code regarding dpkt for ipv6

```
    # For each packet in the pcap process the contents
    for ts, buf in pcap:

        # Unpack the Ethernet frame (mac src/dst, ethertype)
        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(buf)

        # Make sure the Ethernet frame contains an IP packet
        # EtherType (IP, ARP, PPPoE, IP6... see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType)
        if eth.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP6:
            print 'Non IP Packet type not supported %s\n' % eth.data.__class__.__name__
            continue

        # Now unpack the data within the Ethernet frame (the IP packet) 
        # Pulling out src, dst, length, fragment info, TTL, and Protocol
    ipv6 = eth.data
    fh = dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_FRAGMENT
    ic = dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_ICMP6
    icmpv6 = ipv6.data


    # get src and dst ip address    
    src_ip = socket.inet_ntop(AF_INET6, ipv6.src)
    dst_ip = socket.inet_ntop(AF_INET6, ipv6.dst)


        # Analyzing pcap file offline
        #if packet.haslayer(IPv6) and pkt[IPv6].nh == 44 and dpkt.ip6.IP6FragmentHeader.nxt==60 and dpkt.ip6.IP6HopOptsHeader.nxt == 58:
    if ipv6.v == 6 and ipv6.nxt==44:

        print ipv6.IP6FragmentHeader.nxt
```

UPDATE: when I use dpkt.ip6.IP6FragmentHeader i get this error

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'IP6FragmentHeader'

I want get the fragmentation header from this packet which is ICMPv6
[wireshark packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCcAR.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and it was related to the version I am using. I've updated the version and the issue been resolved.

Regards